# Filling NULL values with preceding Non-NULL values using FIRST_VALUE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am joining two tables.

In the first table, I have some items starting at a specific time. In the second table, I have values and timestamps for each minute in between the start and end time of each item.

First table

```
UniqueID  Items start_time
123       one   10:00 AM
456       two   11:00 AM
789       three 11:30 AM
```

Second table

```
UniqueID Items time_hit  value
123      one   10:00 AM    x
123      one   10:05 AM    x
123      one   10:10 AM    x
123      one   10:30 AM    x
456      two   11:00 AM    x
456      two   11:15 AM    x
789      three 11:30 AM    x
```

So When joining the two tables I have this:

```
UniqueID Items start_time  time_hit   value 
123      one   10:00 AM    10:00 AM   x
123      null  null        10:05 AM   x
123      null  null        10:10 AM   x
123      null  null        10:30 AM   x
456      two   11:00 AM    11:00 AM   x
456      null  null        11:15 AM   x
789      three 11:30 AM    11:30 AM   x
```

I'd like to replace these `null` values with the values from the non-null precedent row...

So the expected result is

```
UniqueID Items start_time  time_hit   value 
123      one   10:00 AM    10:00 AM   x
123      one   10:00 AM    10:05 AM   x
123      one   10:00 AM    10:10 AM   x
123      one   10:00 AM    10:30 AM   x
456      two   11:00 AM    11:00 AM   x
456      two   11:00 AM    11:15 AM   x
789      three 11:30 AM    11:30 AM   x
```

I tried to build my join using the following function without success:

```
  FIRST_VALUE(Items IGNORE NULLS) OVER (
    PARTITION BY time_hit ORDER BY time_hit
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND
    UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS test
```

---

My question was a bit off. I found out that UniqueID were inconsistent that is why I had these null values in my output. So the validated answer is a good option to fill null-values when joining two tables and one of your tables has more unique rows than the other.

Comment: Please provide your expected result. Do you also mean "proceeding row containing `not null` values"?

Comment: Let me know if it is clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `first_value` (but `last_value` would also work too in this scenario). The import part is to specify `rows between unbounded preceding and current row` to set the boundaries of the window.

**Answer updated to reflect updated question, and preference for `first_value`**

```
select
first_value(t1.UniqueId ignore nulls) over (partition by t2.UniqueId
                                           order by t2.time_hit
                                           rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as UniqueId,
first_value(t1.items ignore nulls) over (partition by t2.UniqueId
                                        order by t2.time_hit
                                        rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Items,
first_value(t1.start_time ignore nulls) over (partition by t2.UniqueId
                                        order by t2.time_hit
                                        rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as start_time,
t2.time_hit,
t2.item_value
from table2 t2
left join table1 t1 on t1.start_time = t2.time_hit
order by t2.time_hit;
```

**Result**

```
| UNIQUEID | ITEMS | START_TIME | TIME_HIT | ITEM_VALUE |
|----------|-------|------------|----------|------------|
|      123 |   one |   10:00:00 | 10:00:00 |          x |
|      123 |   one |   10:00:00 | 10:05:00 |          x |
|      123 |   one |   10:00:00 | 10:10:00 |          x |
|      123 |   one |   10:00:00 | 10:30:00 |          x |
|      456 |   two |   11:00:00 | 11:00:00 |          x |
|      456 |   two |   11:00:00 | 11:15:00 |          x |
|      789 | three |   11:30:00 | 11:30:00 |          x |
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45fe06/3)

*Note: I had to use Oracle in SQL Fiddle (so I had to change the data types and a column name). But it should work for your database.*

Comment: so that exactly the same function I've used except that it is last_value instead of first_value... right?

Comment: The functions are from the same family, but have different features. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#navigation-functions

Comment: In this situation, either `first_value` or `last_value` would work, because `NULL`s are removed and only one row exists in the window. Values are set by the `rows between unbounded preceding and current row` condition. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Better to partition by the `UniqueID` for better performance, as long as it is consistent with the `Items` value.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative solution would be to use a `NOT EXISTS` clause as `JOIN` condition, with a correlated subquery that ensures that we are relating to the relevant record.

```
SELECT t1.items, t1.start_time, t2.time_hit, t2.value
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON  t1.items = t2.items
    AND t1.start_time <= t2.time_hit  
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM table1 t10
        WHERE 
            t10.items = t2.items 
            AND t10.start_time <= t2.time_hit
            AND t10.start_time > t1.start_time
    )
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3vdGqMNwhGF19UxdmAcger/0)**:

```
| items | start_time | time_hit | value |
| ----- | ---------- | -------- | ----- |
| one   | 10:00:00   | 10:00:00 | x     |
| one   | 10:00:00   | 10:05:00 | x     |
| one   | 10:00:00   | 10:10:00 | x     |
| one   | 10:00:00   | 10:30:00 | x     |
| two   | 11:00:00   | 11:00:00 | x     |
| two   | 11:00:00   | 11:15:00 | x     |
| three | 11:30:00   | 11:30:00 | x     |
```

---

Alternative solution to avoid using `EXISTS` on a `JOIN` condition (not allowed in Big Query): just move that condition to the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT t1.items, t1.start_time, t2.time_hit, t2.value
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON  t1.items = t2.items
    AND t1.start_time <= t2.time_hit  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM table1 t10
    WHERE 
        t10.items = t2.items 
        AND t10.start_time <= t2.time_hit
        AND t10.start_time > t1.start_time
)
```

**[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3vdGqMNwhGF19UxdmAcger/1)**

Comment: I have the following error `EXISTS subquery is not supported inside join predicate.
`

Comment: @SimonBreton: ok... Updated my answer with an alternative query (functionaly equivalent to the previous query, but without usihng `EXISTS` as a `JOIN` condition)

Comment: Ok I can run the query (don't have the error anymore) but It doesn't work. I'm actually using a unique ID to join the two tables. Does this can impact your solution?

Comment: @SimonBreton: well, my query seems to run fine and return the expected output, given the sample data that you provided... I can see that you edited your post to add the `UniqueID` column: this is not a good practice on SO. You might want to ask a new question, providing more explanation on your goal and different sample data/expected output.

Comment: Ok sorry about that... what sould I do? I can't open the exact same question with just a different sample or yes?

Comment: @SimonBreton: you can ask a new question, but I think that would need to make it clearer. As it is, I must confess that your (modified) requirement is not very clear to me (eg, if you have a `uniqueID` that relates two tables, why not simply use it to `JOIN` them instead of using window functions or a correlated subquery?). You would probably need to provide a better explanation and sample data that really makes your point.

Comment: I think you're right, my question is not clear enough. I'm using a simple left join and I have these nulls value. But based on your reaction; I'm actually wondering if there isn't simply something wrong with my join. I will open a new question. Thanks. Still, the answer from @bruceskyaus is working.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are expecting an output by using INNER JOIN. But not sure why you used FIRST_VALUE.

```
SELECT I.Item, I.Start_Time, ID.Time_hit,  ID.Value
FROM Items I
INNER JOIN ItemDetails ID
 ON I.Items = ID.Items
```

Please explain if you are looking for any specific reasons to look over this approach.

Comment: I guess my question is not clear enough... yes I've used an inner join to join the two tables... still I have these nulls values. Please let me know how I can clarify. Thanks.